# Sublime text - how to select HTML table columns?

Tags: html, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

In Sublime Text, is it possible to select the cells of a specific column in  an HTML table? Assume there's no common attribute to hook onto (such as class or position at the end of a row) so multi-select isn't helpful in this context.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>col 1.1</td>
    <td>col 2.1 - I'd like to select this</td>
    <td>col 3.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>col 1.2</td>
    <td>col 2.2 - ...and this</td>
    <td>col 3.3</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Your TD contains col 2.2 . Is it there in actual data or not? Are there any classes or ids of td elements?

Comment: @AdityaJoshi Nope, that's not actual data. The real data I'm working with is super random (variously formatted postal addresses to be exact). No IDs or classes on the td elements.

Answer (score 2):

Do the following

- Select `<tr>`
- Press `ALT + F3`
- Press `down arrow` as many times as required (so that each cursor is on the right column)
- Move cursor `right` so it is at the end of `<td>`
- Press `SHIFT + End`. Maintain `SHIFT` pressed and press `left arrow` 5 times

Answer (score 0):

To perform SEARCH AND/OR REPLACE, open replace box using Ctrl+H or menu (Find>Replace). In the bottom bar, select the first button that enables regular expressions. It looks like [.*]. There will be two boxes - first one for search, second one to write the replacement.

Search for :

```
(<tr>\s+<td>.+</td>\s+<td>)(.+)(</td>)\n
```

This will find and select upto second TD in each row.

Now you wish to replace only content of second TD. That's done using regex groups marked by brackets. So you can write

```
$1 REPLACEMENT $3
```

in the second textbox marked "Replace With". I love Sublime Text mainly because of its regex capabilities like VIM but far more simple and intuitive interface.